# Twilio bulk sms queue with unique message for each recipient

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-api, bulksms

I am trying to find an api call for sending or queueing bulk sms with a single api call with unique message for each recipient instead of calling twilio api `n` number of times.

Is there a way to achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no bulk API for sending personalised SMS messages with Twilio. You can [send bulk SMS messages with one API request](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/12/send-bulk-sms-twilio-node-js.html) as long as those messages are the same.

You will have to send one API call per different message you want to send. If you want to speed up this process, you can use a [Messaging Service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/send-messages-copilot) and add  multiple numbers to the associated number pool. This will increase the rate at which messages can be sent, allowing you to complete the task quicker.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks, this was a great help.

Comment: If I call sms api for 1000 sms or more, will that create any problem, and shouldn't `Twilio` have a bulk call so their server doesn't get high load?

Comment: Twilio doesn't have a bulk API call for personalised messages right now. The issue you need to pay attention to is that you can make 100 concurrent requests to the Twilio API. If you try to make more than 100 concurrent requests then you will get rate limited. All you need to do is ensure your concurrent requests are 100 or lower.

Comment: what If I do it synchronously, will there be any rate limiting issue?

Comment: If you make 1000 API calls one after another, synchronously, then there will only be one concurrent call at a time so you will not have rate limiting problems.

Comment: Is this still unsupported in 2022? The issue is that with thousands of messages the server calling SMS create will eventually timeout sequentially (i.e. firebase functions has max 9 minute timeout). Is there no better solution?

Comment: This is still the case. But if you need to send thousands of messages I wouldn't recommend doing it all in the same function. If you are using Firebase, check out the [Twilio Messaging extension for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/twilio-send-message) where you can send messages by simply adding them to a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Using notification service https://www.twilio.com/console/notify/getting-started you can send upto 10000 message in single API call, but in this case you cann't send personalisation message.